# Once POST or GET request is sent from browser, is the request data stored somewhere in browser or local machine?

Tags: google-chrome, post, get, header-files

I recently sent off some form data as a POST request using chrome using windows 7.  The server returned a response page.  Not wanting to repeat the lengthy process of filling out the form again, I would like to know if my browser or computer keeps a log of all the request data sent in my POST/GET requests (header files).  If so, where can I find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... probably better at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Browsers aren't required to keep any information you send via get or post.  Browsers may keep some of it, or they may not.  It's entirely implementation specific, additionally specific to what type of data is being sent, and further specific to your own configuration.  For example: Many (but not all) browsers can store userid and passwords.  This feature may be turned on or off for a specific user, and a user may elect to not participate in that feature for a given site as well.  Address storage is an other example, but this time fewer browsers participate. Plugins can change everything too.

Answer (score 0):

your company will not save the data anyway by default. it was on the RAM! i think you probably want to enable cookies.